# How to create separate images containing one instance mask per image from a single image with multiple masks in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have the following image:

[image]

Each mask is for an individual instance. I want to have separate images which will contain only one instance mask per image. Masks are not overlapping strictly. The outputs will be as like following:

[image] [image] [image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an answer to this. The following code segment creates the desired output:

```
def create_separate_mask(path):
    # get all the masks
    for mask_file in glob.glob(path + '/*mask.png'): 
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_file, 1)
        # get masks labelled with different values
        label_im, nb_labels = ndimage.label(mask) 

        for i in range(nb_labels):

            # create an array which size is same as the mask but filled with 
            # values that we get from the label_im. 
            # If there are three masks, then the pixels are labeled 
            # as 1, 2 and 3.

            mask_compare = np.full(np.shape(label_im), i+1) 

            # check equality test and have the value 1 on the location of each mask
            separate_mask = np.equal(label_im, mask_compare).astype(int) 

            # replace 1 with 255 for visualization as rgb image

            separate_mask[separate_mask == 1] = 255 
            base=os.path.basename(mask_file)

            # give new name to the masks

            file_name = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
            file_copy = os.path.join(path, file_name + "_" + str(i+1) +".png") 
            cv2.imwrite(file_copy, separate_mask)
```